# Variable defined in feature file is not getting in .js file

Tags: karate

In my feature file i have defined a variable .I am executing karate.map() after that. In the calling js function used in the karate.map() is using the defined variable. It was working with earlier karate version. With karate 1.4, it is throwing an error like " that variable is not defined".

```
Background:
  * def getItem= read('test.js')

Scenario:
* def sampleItem = "tests"
* def sampleitems = locateAll("#item")
* def itemMap = karate.map(sampleitems, getItem)
```

this is the tests.js file

```
function fn(itemVal) {
 some codes
karae.log(sampleItem);
}
```

In the getItem js function , i am using 'sampleItem' .  But it throws the error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Going to give this a shot.

based on the info you have provided, it looks like the issue is either 
A - you have defined `sampleItem` , but are passing something different : `sampleitems`

B - `sampleItem` is not "list-like"

If neither of these things are actually issues, please refer to [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
[json-transforms](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#json-transforms) 
[map](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#karate-map)

Answer (score 1):

Question is not very clear and also observed that in the below code there is a mismatch in the name of the variable i.e sampleItem is not same as sampleitems

- def sampleItem = "tests"
- def itemMap = karate.map(sampleitems, getItem)

Comment: I just edited my example with more info... both are different variables.. one is a list and one is a string variable

Comment: Actually i got the issue solved. The background section to import the js file was in another parent feature file (which was working early). Now i imported in the calling feature file and that resolved.